# Register Memberships with Advanced Custom Fields

Tags: wordpress, field, advanced-custom-fields, membership

I'm currently trying to figure out a process of creating a paid membership account using Advanced Custom Fields.

What I'm trying to do is create a directory with Advanced Custom Fields & Custom Post Types, which is easy enough to do but what I need to happen is:

User creates a basic account without paying for membership

This directs to the Advanced Custom Fields form where users can create a new "Post Type" with their information, If someone chooses one particular radio button, it needs to show a link to the designated membership level (eg: Gold)

The user then clicks on the link to the correct membership level and sorts out payment details

Everything is then set up and posted once the last step is complete

---

I've bought the Advanced Custom Fields plugin and was thinking of using "Ultimate Membership Pro" plugin to achieve this but I'm just trying to figure out how to link it all together.

All help is massively appreciated.